# Clone and dynamically set input name value

Tags: jquery, dom, clone

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nb2U/)

This appears to be somewhat complex, so I'm trying to be as general as possible. Please look at the fiddle to make more sense out of it.

The general idea is to set a text input's name attribute to the preceding selected option's value of a drop down. It works well enough. The trouble starts when you 'add filter' it is cloning the text input, and using the same name attribute value. I'm submitting the data as json, and the name attribute of the text input is setting the "key" of the "key/value" pair. This results in submitting two parameters that both have the same "key". I can only seem to update the text input's name attribute on a change event. The below line is the cause.

```
$('.js-selectblock > .js-select:first').clone().appendTo('.js-selectblock');
```

I've tried some stuff like `.clone(false).find('input[type="text"]).attr('name','FOO').appendTo('.js-selectblock')`

but that only clones the text input and I have no way of knowing what to set the name value to. The code is disabling the previously selected values in the drop down, which eliminates being able to select the same value multiple times, I need to figure out a way to also dynamically set the text input's name attribute to match the selected value from the drop down.

tl;dr - need a better routine to dynamically add search filters, based on the number of select list options. The cloned text input's name attribute needs to match the value of its sibling select list's selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do it this way:

```
$('.js-selectblock > .js-select:first').clone().appendTo('.js-selectblock').find('input[type="text"]').attr('name','foo');
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nb2U/1/)

You must use `appendTo()` first before using `find()`.

`find()` returns only the selected element which is the textbox so only the textbox will be appended.